# Removing stuck faucet handle

Tags: plumbing

Any Suggestions for how to remove a stuck faucet handle? I have removed the setscrew and pulled hard upwards and the handle, but it won’t come off. I sprayed WD-40, but no luck. I’m just not sure how hard to force this off or if there something I’m missing?

Comment: A picture would help a lot. If you have a model number or other identifying details that would help too

Answer (score 1):

If there is a set screw that holds it to the stem it is *very likely* (but not 100% certain) that it pulls directly off. You have soaked it with some penetrating lube, now try gently tapping it from various angles to loosen it prior to re-attempting to pull it off.

If this does not work, purchase (or fabricate) a "faucet handle puller". They exist because your problem is fairly common:

[image]